# Swift: UICollectionViewController not displaying any cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Non of the other question on this topic have worked for me so here goes this one.

No cells are appearing despite, I am programmatically presenting the `UICollectionViewController` from a `UIViewController` that is in Storyboard

Note: `@IBAction` segue is just a button action

This is the `UIViewController`:

```
@IBAction func segue(sender: AnyObject) {
    let collectionview = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    self.presentViewController(collectionview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then this is the `UICollectionViewController`:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
      self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }


  // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

  override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }


  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 10
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
      return cell
  }

}
```

I must be missing something obvious. Thanks in advance to the person who points it out for me.

Comment: Cell size missing? Also check for setting delegate and datasource of your collection view.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan no unfortunately that isn't the issue, and delegate and data source don't need to be set as it is a UICollectionViewController, thanks though

Answer (score 9):

I figured out the problem, a bit silly really. When presenting the new `UICollectionViewController` I initialized it wrong. I used `UICollectionViewLayout` when I needed to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
@IBAction func segue(sender: AnyObject) {
    let collectionview = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    self.presentViewController(collectionview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: wow thank you bro !! i did this stupid mistake too.. you saved my time !! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I took a jab at it and got this to work:

In your viewDidLoad() method, try this:

```
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width - 25

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/4, height: screenWidth/4)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5

    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

I guess the issue lay in not specifying a UICollectionViewFlowLayout for the cells. This adds 5px spacing between each cell but you can change that if you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, this does work but it is very long winded. Read my answer I just posted to see the one word mistake I made that fixed it :)

Comment: Great, glad you solved it! Just took some code from a project of mine so sorry if it was a bit long haha

Comment: no worries thanks for posting your answer anyway, still informative